# How to trim the column values using Spark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**I have a dataframe like below, and I need to trim the values in SCHDULE column using spark dataframe.**
*I tried with UDF functions but I didn't get expected output*

| SCHDULE | ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100H/10AR1 | KL01 | 30 |
| 100H/10TR2 | KL01 | 40 |
| 100H/22TR1 | KL01 | 20 |
| 100H/22TR2 | KL01 | 20 |
| 105JK/12PK1 | AA05 | 10 |
| 105JK/12PK2 | AA05 | 20 |
| 105JH/33PK3 | AA05 | 50 |
| 105JH/33PK4 | AA05 | 30 |
| 110P/1 | BR03 | 20 |
| 110P/2 | BR03 | 10 |

**I need output like the below dataframe, can anyone pls help me on this**

| SCHDULE | ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100H/10AR1 | KL01 | 30 |
| 100H/10TR2 | KL01 | 40 |
| 100H/22TR1 | KL01 | 20 |
| 100H/22TR2 | KL01 | 20 |
| 105JK/12PK1 | AA05 | 10 |
| 105JK/12PK2 | AA05 | 20 |
| 105JH/33PK3 | AA05 | 50 |
| 105JH/33PK4 | AA05 | 30 |
| 110P/1 | BR03 | 20 |
| 110P/2 | BR03 | 10 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you dont need udf here, use function from Spark API, in this case regexp_extract may be usefull, below you can find sample code and regexp

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val inputData = Seq(
  "100H/10AR1",
  "105J/33PK4",
  "110P/1"
)

val inputDf = inputData.toDF("SCHDULE")
inputDf.withColumn("Trimmed", regexp_extract($"SCHDULE","""^(\d+[A-Z]?\/\d+).*""",1)).show
```

Output:

```
+----------+-------+
|   SCHDULE|Trimmed|
+----------+-------+
|100H/10AR1|100H/10|
|105J/33PK4|105J/33|
|    110P/1| 110P/1|
+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Hi M_S thanks for the answer, but some rows are showing as empty in the Trimmed column.

Comment: example, when the SCHEDULE value is 105JK/12PK1 at that time value shows as null in the Trimmed column.

Comment: It is hard to provide correct regexp because i dont now your whole dataset. I saw only your sample records. You can try something like this: """^(\w+\/\d+).*""" BTW i think that you edited your questions and now output dataset looks the same as input

Comment: FYI Its called a regexp, not UDF